# Removing load balancer ip from "x-forwarded-for" header in google cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, devops

I'm Using google cloud to serve my application.

When i add a load balancer in front of my app, the load balancer ip is appended to the "x-forwarded-for" header (alongside  the user's host ip) in the each session request to the server.

**My question is how can i configure the load balancer not to append his ip on each user request?**

Attaching the load balancer settings in google cloud, i can't see any advanced configurations here:

[image]

Comment: Found also this useful discussion - (check the comments for the accepted answer):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246089/getting-orgin-ip-from-load-balancer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X-Forwarded-For` is a [standard HTTP request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) and, as such, the LB is doing the right thing by maintaining it in the request that lands on the backend. You can read more about its use in Google Cloud [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components).

As far as I know, there's no way to strip away request headers at the LB level in Google Cloud. You can, however, create custom headers. Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#user-defined-request-headers) for more information on that.